# PermanentRedirect when calling the PutObject operation

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

The code below work locally and uploads files from a directory to S3. It's using Boto3 with Python 3.

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET)
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
uploadFileNames = []
for (sourceDir, dirname, filenames) in os.walk(sourceDir):
    for filename in filenames:
        bucket.put_object(Key=filename, Body=open("{}{}".format(sourceDir, filename), "rb"))
    break
```

My problem is what when I run the same code on my production server (Ubuntu) I get the following error, why?

```
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 335, in _make_api_call
    raise ClientError(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (PermanentRedirect) when calling the PutObject operation: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
```

Again locally on my Mac this code works, it is only on my Ubuntu server I get this error.

Comment: That error reminds me of situation where I've tried to access a bucket from the wrong region. Perhaps running `aws configure` on both machines and check that you have the same default region?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I don't want to configure AWS on the Ubuntu machine like that. Could I set the region programmatically in Boto3? The buckets are in region EU west.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein you are right!!!! I solved this be setting ``boto3.setup_default_session(region_name='eu-west-1')`` . Could you post an answer so other may benefit and I can accept?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The errors says:

> An error occurred (**PermanentRedirect**) when calling the PutObject operation: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the **specified endpoint**. Please send all future requests to this **endpoint**.

This typically occurs when the Amazon S3 bucket you are using is **in a different Region** to where the Amazon S3 client was created.

For example, the bucket is in `us-west-2` but the client was created for `ap-southeast-2`.

You can specify the region [via a credentials file](https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/quickstart.html#configuration), or by passing a `region_name` when creating the client object. A default region can also be defined in [`boto3.setup_default_session()`](https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/core/boto3.html?boto3.setup_default_session).