# How to load JSON data (call from API) without key directly to S3 bucket using Python?

Tags: json, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am relatively new to AWS `s3` I am calling an API to load the JSON data directly to `s3` bucket. From `s3` bucket data will be read by `Snowflake`. After researching I found that using `Boto3` we can load data into `s3` directly. Code will look something like below, however one thing I am not sure about is What should I put for the key as there is no object created in my `S3` bucket. Also, what is the good practice to load the JSON data to `s3` ? Do I need to encode JSON data to 'UTF-8' as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46844263/writing-json-to-file-in-s3-bucket) by SO user Uwe Bretschneider.

Thanks in advance!

**Python code:**

```
import json,urllib.request
import boto3
data = urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.github.com/users?since=100").read()
output = json.loads(data) 
print (output) #Checking the data


s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.put_object(
     Body=str(json.dumps(data))
     Bucket='I_HAVE_BUCKET_NAME'
     Key='your_key_here'
)
```

Comment: Key is analogous to path.  It's just a name you use to reference the data in the bucket, it can be whatever you like and you don't need to create a parent path in S3.  So you could specify 'a/b/c/d.json' without 'a/b/c' previously existing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `put_object`, which means you are creating a new object in the bucket, so there is no existing key.
This key is just like a file name in the file system. You can specify whatever names you like, such as `my-data.json` or `some-dir/my-data.json`. You can find out more in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-keys.html.

As for encoder, it's always good to specify the encoding IMO, just to make sure your source file has properly encoded too.

Comment: Thank you! Where should I put encoder in my above code ? I am receiving "TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable"

Comment: Played with the code for a while, think you can use `output` directly:

`output = json.loads(data.decode('utf-8'))`
...
`Body=str(json.dumps(output ))`

see if that helps, could ignore my previous comment.